# sum group of rows starting at value x and going until value y encountered and then repeat

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to group rows together starting at the point where the value is greater than 0 and then going until the value is back at 0 and then repeating through the table.

This is for MySQL 8.0... and I'm not sure where to start with this.

Example table

```
| tag          | value | timestamp                |
|--------------|-------|--------------------------|
| sts_downtime | 0     | 2019-01-03 09:31:40.8240 |
| sts_downtime | 1     | 2019-01-03 09:50:23.0310 |
| sts_downtime | 3     | 2019-01-03 09:53:07.7750 |
| sts_downtime | 4     | 2019-01-03 09:53:40.6060 |
| sts_downtime | 0     | 2019-01-04 08:48:27.1020 |
| sts_downtime | 0     | 2019-01-04 13:30:26.5180 |
| sts_downtime | 10    | 2019-01-04 14:19:56.3740 |
| sts_downtime | 10    | 2019-01-07 08:49:03.8480 |
| sts_downtime | 10    | 2019-01-07 09:34:25.0850 |
| sts_downtime | 0     | 2019-01-07 09:34:53.9940 |
| sts_downtime | 0     | 2019-01-07 12:59:21.3210 |
```

What I'd like to get

```
| Sum of Value | Start                    | End                      |
|--------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
| 8            | 2019-01-03 09:50:23.0310 | 2019-01-03 09:53:40.6060 |
| 30           | 2019-01-04 14:19:56.3740 | 2019-01-07 09:34:25.0850 |
```

Comment: I think you will need an actual programming language to do something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to window functions in MySQL 8. Use them.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, CASE
        WHEN LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) = 0 AND value > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) > 0 AND value = 0 THEN 1 END AS chg
    FROM t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(chg) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS grp
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT SUM(value) AS `Sum of value`, MIN(timestamp) AS `Start`, MAX(timestamp) AS `End`
FROM cte2
GROUP BY grp
HAVING SUM(value) > 0
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ade6893b9770ec6c2d19128b197e29f2)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to get this done with windows, but my experience on them was limited. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

With several CTEs:

```
with 
ctemin as (
  select t.timestamp from tablename t
    where value <> 0 and 
    (select value from tablename where timestamp = 
       (select max(timestamp) from tablename where timestamp < t.timestamp)
    ) = 0
),  
ctemax as (
  select t.timestamp from tablename t
    where value <> 0 and 
    (select value from tablename where timestamp = 
       (select min(timestamp) from tablename where timestamp > t.timestamp)
    ) = 0
),
cte as (
  select 
    t.timestamp Start,
    (select min(timestamp) from ctemax 
     where timestamp >= t.timestamp) End
  from ctemin t
)  

select 
  sum(value) `Sum of Value`,
  c.Start, c.End
from cte c inner join tablename t
on t.timestamp between c.Start and c.End
group by c.Start, c.End
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQDeAKJiTCTcJ5MEHtY7pi/1).
Results:

```
| Sum of Value | Start                      | End                        |
| ------------ | -------------------------- | -------------------------- |
| 8            | 2019-01-03 09:50:23.031000 | 2019-01-03 09:53:40.606000 |
| 30           | 2019-01-04 14:19:56.374000 | 2019-01-07 09:34:25.085000 |
```